# How to model this easy problem as sum of indicator random variables in order to apply Chernoff bound

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation, distribution-tails

Do you have an idea how I could model the following process somehow as a sum of independent indicator random variables?

I have given a grid of size $n \times n$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Now I color each point of this grid uniformly at random with one out of $k$ colors, where $k=\mathcal{O}(1)$.

I am interested in the probability that none of the $3 \times 3$-subgrids in this grid are monochromatic (monochromatic=all 9 points have the same color) and should show this probability is at most $e^{- \Omega(n^2)}$.

My task is explicitly to model this such that I can use Chernoff bounds. 
Chernoff bounds, in the context we had it, can be applied if we have a sum $X:=\sum_{i=1}^m X_i$ of independent indicator random variables $X_i \sim Be(p_i)$.

My problem is that clearly the different $3 \times 3$ grids are *not* independent, so the easy approach to state $X=\sum_{s \in S} X_s$ where $S$ is the set of all $3\times 3$ subgrids and $X_s$ is $1$ if $s$ is a monochromatic grid, and calculate $P[X=0]$ does not work.

Would be very happy about any hint. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: This is most likely not good, but my first hazy idea would be to apply Chernoff bounds independently to the $k$ colors, to bound the probability that each of them has density too big (a necessary, but not sufficient condition for what you want); and then take a union bound over the $k=O(1)$ events.

Comment: Thank you for your idea! I am not sure whether I got it, however. 
Because now I tried to model it like this: Let $X_j$ be the number of points that are colored with color $j$. Clearly, $X_j \sim Bin(n^2, \frac{1}{k})$ 
If there is a monochromatic subgrid of color $j$, then $X_j \geq 9$. 
We would then say that $P[ \text{exists monochromatic grid}] \leq k P[\text{exists monochromatic grid of color j}] \leq k P[ X_j \geq 9]$
However, $P[X_j \geq 9]$  cannot be calculated using Chernoff bounds, since $9 < E[X_j]=\frac{n^2}{k}$ (thus no tail estimate). So I would need another density, but which?

Comment: This is not true.  Suppose $n$ is a multiple of 3. You can partition your grid into $(n/3)^2$ disjoint $3\times 3$ sub grids.  Each (independently) does _not_ have all the same color with probability $1-1/k^8$.  So the probability that _none_ of these sub grids have all the same color is $(1-1/k^8)^{(n/3)^2}$. Since $k$ is fixed, this goes to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Yet, you claim the probability goes to 1.

Comment: I fixed that. Thank you for the hint, Michael.

Comment: To get just an upper bound, notice that Michael's event will do the job. Namely, your event implies that the event described by Michael is true and you only require an upper bound as per your question. For te lower bound, you will need Chernoff.

Comment: @gmath: it is not clear to me how to use Chernoff here. However, if you define $z$ as the probability that a $3\times 3$ grid has a checkerboard pattern of alternating colors, then if all $(n/3)^2$ of the disjoint $3\times 3$ grids in the original partition have this property, there can be no monochrome $3\times 3$ grid anywhere else.  So $Pr[none] \geq z^{(n/3)^2}$.  So both upper and lower bounds on $Pr[none]$ have the form $e^{-a n^2}$ for some positive constant $a$.

Comment: Yes you are right, I dont know what I was thinking.  :)